# How can insert BFILE values in oracle using java?

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to create sample in which i have insert BFILE datatype values using following java program.

```
   public class ImportDriver
{
    public static void main (String args [])
            throws Exception
    {
        // Load the Oracle JDBC driver:
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

        // Connect to the database:
        Connection conn =
                DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:oracledb", "User1", "password");
        conn.setAutoCommit (false);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();       

        try
        {          

            stmt.execute ("insert into test_dir_table values ('test', bfilename ('C:\\temp\\TEST_DIR', 'file1'))");
            stmt.execute ("insert into test_dir_table values ('test2', bfilename ('C:\\temp\\TEST_DIR', 'file6'))");
            stmt.execute ("insert into test_dir_table values ('test1', bfilename ('TEST_DIR', 'file2.gif'))");
            // Commit the transaction:
            conn.commit();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

By using above mention program value are inserted into table but when i see values of BFILE using oracle development tool than inserted images were not showing.

please suggest how can I insert BFILE value into table using java program?

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods from the oracle.sql package to handle BFILE type, [here is the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oralob.htm).